# MYSQL Workbench Installation - Schemas Not connected

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, workbench

I am new to SQL and just installed MYSQL Workbench in an attempt to make my first database.  I thought the installation went fine but when I click on Schemas it says "Not connected" and doesn't show any Schemas.  From what I understand, there should be a default schema there to use.

I did also have to create a connection when i first opened workbench as there was no default there (from what I understand there should have been a default after installation).

How can I check if my installation went ok or if there is something i'm missing?  Also, how can i connect to the default Schema?

Comment: Did you install MySQL Server? Your description seem to indicate that you only install MySQL Workbench.. that's only a tool

Comment: Thanks tcadidot0.  That's what the issue was.  Once I install mysql server the issue was resolved.